# @Input not validating data type

Tags: angular, components

Having two components (app.component and other.component) and passing via @Input a value from app.component to other.component I can pass a seemingly invalid value but it still works.

I have tried this with basic data types and classes and works equally in both cases. For simplicity I will provide an example with basic types.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zhjthy

**app.component.ts** (note 'value' is a string)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  value: string = 'this is a String';
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-other [value]="value"></app-other>
```

**other.component.ts** (note '@Input() value' is a boolean)

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-other',
  templateUrl: './other.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./other.component.css']
})
export class OtherComponent {
  @Input() value: boolean;
}
```

**other.component.html**

```
<p>{{value}} <-- this should be a boolean</p>
```

Result looks like:

```
this is a String <-- this should be a boolean
```

How is this working? Are TS types only useful at compile but then ignored at runtime? Is there any way to enforce this type validation (wether at compile or runtime)?

Comment: *"Are TS types ... ignored at runtime?"* - they **don't exist** at runtime, they're stripped out in the transpilation to JS, because otherwise the output wouldn't be valid JS.

Comment: I know, but it may (o may not) be possible to transfer type information to JS and check it at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is not there yet I think. But If you build in aot you can set.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": { ... },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true
        ...
    }
}
```

which performs some template type checking.

```
ng build --aot
```

But that will slow you development build down i guess. Try your prod build with above setting and you might get some error there? I read somewhere that IVY(next version of angular renderer) have more template checks

But I have not had so much issues with missing typecheck in templates. And I been working with a LOT of project. Weird really

Comment: Not a problem, just something weird we found.

Answer (score 1):

In the runtime, typescript code is transpiled (converted) to JavaScript so that browser can understand it, and javascript doesn't check data type, therefore it is working.